Looking for title of an old show for teens
I used to watch an old TV show for teens in which a girl got soaked in some stuff that fell off a truck (it was in barrels). And from that point, she could melt and slide under doors and reform in her original shape. There was also a girl (her sister?) that wanted to figure out how she could melt and reform her shape, there were also other people that are the creators of the stuff in the barrels and they wanted to get her to silence her or something (it was a long time ago :)
Please help...

It's The Secret World of Alex Mack, I remember some episodes so I instantly recognized the series you were referring to, although I didn't remember the title. 

Plot:
Alex Mack is an ordinary teenage girl, living with her parents and older sister in the corporate town of Paradise Valley. After her first day of junior high school, while walking home, Alex is nearly hit by a truck from a chemical plant, and during the incident, she is drenched with a top-secret chemical called GC-161. She soon discovers that the chemical gives her strange powers. These include telekinesis, plus the ability to transmit bolts of electricity through her fingers, or morph into liquid form. However, her powers prove to be unpredictable (such as when her skin starts glowing brightly while she's nervous). She confides only in her sister Annie, and her best friend Ray, about her powers and decides to keep them a secret from everyone else, including her parents, for fear of what the chemical plant CEO, Danielle Atron, will do to her if she finds out.

